# How can we find a good upper bound for $\sum_i \frac{a_i}{b_i}$ in terms of $\frac{\sum_i a_i}{\sum_i b_i}$?

Tags: inequality

I've been thinking about inequalities of the kind:

$$\frac{\sum_i a_i}{\sum_i b_i}\leq \sum_i \frac{a_i}{b_i} \qquad a_i,b_i>0$$

For some cases, it is easy to see why it works, for example:

$$\frac{a_1+a_2}{b_1+b_2}\leq \frac{a_1}{b_1}+\frac{a_2}{b_2}\qquad a_i,b_i>0$$

We write

$$0\leq a_1b_2^2+a_2b_1^2$$

And then:

$$a_1b_1b_2+a_2b_1b_2 \leq a_1b_1b_2+a_2b_1b_2+ a_1b_2^2+a_2b_1^2$$

Finally:

$$b_1b_2(a_1+a_2)\leq (a_1b_2+a_2b_1)(b_1+b_2)$$

Which yields the desired inequality:

$$\frac{a_1+a_2}{b_1+b_2}\leq \frac{a_1}{b_1}+\frac{a_2}{b_2}$$

I am curious about the following:

- How can we find a good upper bound for $\sum_i \frac{a_i}{b_i}$ in terms of $\frac{\sum_i a_i}{\sum_i b_i}$? In my hypothetical application for this, obtaining the number $\frac{\sum_i a_i}{\sum_i b_i}$  is very easy but obtaining $\sum_i \frac{a_i}{b_i}$ would be very messy. Having a good upper bound in terms of $\frac{\sum_i a_i}{\sum_i b_i}$ would be desirable. I know next to nothing about inequalities. I guessed about squares, cubes of $\frac{\sum_i a_i}{\sum_i b_i}$ but this would perhaps be too large. I guess I don't know how to find better upper bounds in terms of $\frac{\sum_i a_i}{\sum_i b_i}$.

Comment: Titu's Lemma ${}$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire No, it is not.

Comment: @Billy Rubina:  What are you expecting? It's obvious after expanding

Comment: Are you looking for an upper bound or lower bound for $\sum \frac{a_i}{b_i}$?  In the $a_1, a_2$ example you gave, its a lower bound that's shown.  A lower bound is easy using CS inequality.

Comment: An upper bound isnt likely, just consider any one $b_i$, say $b_1 \to 0^+$.

Comment: @Macavity Upper bound.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen I wrote what I am expecting in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an upper bound that only depends on $\frac{\sum a_i}{\sum b_i}$ then no.

The quantity $\frac{\sum a_i}{\sum b_i}$ is called the mediant, or freshman sum, of the fractions $\frac{a_i}{b_i}$. It is a weighted average of the fractions so it's always between $\min \frac{a_i}{b_i}$ and $\max \frac{a_i}{b_i}$ and can be arbitrarily close to either. And this is exactly how Simpson's Paradox works.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics)

Now if $n=2$, WLOG assume $\frac{a_1}{b_1} < \frac{a_2}{b_2}$. The mediant can be arbitrarily close to $\frac{a_1}{b_1}$ while the ratio of $\frac{a_2}{b_2}$ to $\frac{a_1}{b_1}$ can also be arbitrarily large. Therefore $\frac{\sum \frac{a_i}{b_i}}{\frac{\sum a_i}{\sum b_i}}$ can be arbitrarily large.

For example, if $N$ is very large, then
$$
\frac{\frac 1N + \frac{N}{1}}{\frac{1+N}{N+1}} = N+\frac 1N > N.
$$

Comment: This is nice. My plan here was trying to find an upper bound for that quantity I judged harder to compute, do you think there is any other way to find a good upper bound for it?

Comment: Can't think of anything without additional information about the $a$'s and $b$'s.

Comment: What kind of information would yield nice results? Can you think on something?

Comment: Say if $m\le b_i \le M$ then $\sum a_i/b_i \le \frac Mm \frac{\sum a_i}{\sum b_i}$

Comment: This is really nice! One curiosity I had: What did you study/read to be able to think so freely about this? I mean, I read what you wrote and I kinda understand it but I wouldn't be able to create something like that on my own. I read a tiny bit of Kazarinoff's "Analytic Inequalities" but the exercises are frequently too hard (at least for me) and I didn't went very far because I had stuff to do at university.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words. Back in high school and college I was lucky enough to have a few genius friends. I learned more from them than from the teachers/professors. Haven't studied any particular inequality books. I think you can just look around and find good peers to learn from. There are many experts in inequality here at Math SE as well. Good luck.